# PDFtk error when doing any command on Mac OS X

Tags: pdftk

We have installed PDFTK server edition on Mac OS X 10.10 and Ubuntu 12 and Ubuntu 14.

When trying to do a `dump_data_fields` for any PDF it seems to throw a weird error before even getting to that operation..

```
$ pdftk SchoolPermissionSlip.pdf dump_data_fields
dyld: _dyld_bind_fully_image_containing_address() error
dyld: Symbol not found: ___emutls_get_address
  Referenced from: /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/../lib/libgcj.11.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/../lib/libgcj.11.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

It's the latest version. Any ideas?

```
pdftk --version

pdftk 2.02 a Handy Tool for Manipulating PDF Documents
Copyright (c) 2003-13 Steward and Lee, LLC - Please Visit: www.pdftk.com
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions. There is
NO warranty, not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Does it work on Ubuntu, but not on OS X?!?? Also, there is no Ubuntu 12 or Ubuntu 14. It's version info comes with an added ***month***, like `12.04` or `12.10` or `14.04` or `14.10`...

Answer (score 7):

We have seen reports of this error intermittently on Mac OS X only.

That `___emutls_get_address` symbol is provided by pdftk's own libgcc_s.1.dylib. The default location for pdftk's libraries on OS X is `/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/lib`. The default location for the pdftk binary is `/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/pdftk`. If you ever move this pdftk binary, it is important to move its libraries along with it so that the pdftk `bin` directory remains siblings with this `lib` directory. This helps ensure that the binary can find its libraries. Perhaps your pdftk binary has been moved without also moving these libraries?

In any case, we have a solution that has worked for others.

Reading the dyld man page, the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable can be used to give precedence to pdftk's libraries. From the Terminal, run:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then test pdftk:

```
pdftk input.pdf dump_data_fields output data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of [PDFtk Server on OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505951/pdftk-server-on-os-x-10-11) but posting our response here too:

We raised this to Sid back in August and he still has not fixed it so I think its fair to say that its a good idea to look for alternatives. Because of this, we have taken the initiative to submit a few first tools that people can enjoy for free in the following repository:

https://github.com/flexpaper/OSX-PDF-Toolkit

It contains easy to use scripts for CAT and BURST. We intend to add more tools going forward. Feel free to contribute

These new tools are using the native OSX libraries and no third party dependencies are needed whatsoever. Yay!