# PDFTK server producing empty pdfs ( El Capitan issue )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, osx-elcapitan

I have a Rails+Angular app (with pdf-forms gem) and one of the main features is generating pdfs for the user. For that feature we use PDFTK server. I was running Yosemite and it was working fine, I updated to El Capitan two days ago, and know PDFTK server generates a pdf but sometimes its empty or it does not generate it at all. I can also run in the command line `pdftk --version` which means pdftk is installed.

I tried to debug it in every way I could think of, I looked at UNIX processes it creates a new processes for creating a certain pdf, I don't have any application level errors ( like in logs or something ) and I really don't know whats going on.

I tried reinstalling PDFTK server that also did not help. My best bet is that something inside of PDFTK is not running correctly.

If anyone had come across similar issue I would love to hear what they know about it.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend that you not even try solving this problem but instead use vagrant to abstract away your development machine host OS.

Get vagrant at https://www.vagrantup.com/ and set it up with the same operating system you use on the server.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, and found a solution by installing a specific installer of PDFTK server for OS X 10.11 El Capitan, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33248310/5538923