# How do I completely remove (all versions of) pdftk server from Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, uninstallation, pdftk

I am having trouble with pdftk on my Mac OS X 10.11 and want to remove all traces of it from my system before attempting to make a new install with the newest package 2.02 (available here on StackOverflow) which I already installed.

I suspect there might be more than one version in my system.

When I try

```
pdftk --version
```

the system gives an error:

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/pdftk
Expected in: /usr/local/bin/../lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
in /usr/local/bin/pdftk
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

and when I run

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

and check for the version I get

```
pdftk 2.02 a Handy Tool for Manipulating PDF Documents
Copyright (c) 2003-13 Steward and Lee, LLC - Please Visit: www.pdftk.com
This is free software; see the source code for copying conditions. There is
NO warranty, not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

How do I remove them from the system?

EDIT:  I actually tried the "version" option on both places,
by going to each folder and typing

```
pdftk --version
```

I got the problem on the /usr/local folder, but the /opt folder printed the version.  It seems I really do have two versions of pdftk on my computer and the default is the problematic one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to uninstall the default pdftk, but the pdftk binary in  /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/pdftk seems to use by default the correct libraries. So in the meantime you could just change your PATH (in .bashrc / .bash_profile) so that the pdftk you use by default if the good one with something like

> export PATH=/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin:$PATH

In the /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin there is also a pdftk_uninstall.sh that will uninstall the /opt/pdflabs when necessary. I guess that will be when pdflabs releases an official updated pdftk that installs the good version in the default directories.

Comment: Basilio, looking at the pdftk_uninstall.sh file, it seems it is set to also remove `/usr/share/man/man1/pdftk.1` and `/usr/local/bin/pdftk`.  I ran the uninstall (with `sudo`) and it removed the binaries, but when I reinstalled the new package, I still got the same error.  The problem is that the package is not setting the path of the libraries to the new installed set (in /opt).   I have the export you stated above in my `.bashrc`, but it seems when I log in the PATH is not set.

Comment: Your are right, I had not checked carefully the pdftk_uninstall.sh In my system just adding the new path  works fine for me. I work with the new pdftk from /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin just fine. Did you try doing the same also in .bash_profile?  Sometimes bash uses .bashrc, other time .bash_prifle

Comment: I tried it, but didn't work (even after restarting system twice).  What I noticed is that when I ran the uninstall, the `/usr/local` binary was removed, but when reinstalled, it was back.  So I figured that the newest package is installing a (default) copy of `pdftk` in `/usr/local`, but looks for the (old) libraries in `../lib/`.  I then moved ALL libraries to a temp folder.  When I typed `pdftk --version` in the Terminal, it worked.  I don't think I need any of the (old) libraries in that folder (but I will keep a safe backup of them just in case).  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Even though your answer didn't actually work for me, it helped me find a solution.  So I will accept it.

Comment: Thank you. Very interesting. I also learned from your explanation. I cannot get rid of those libraries because I need them for other things, so good for me my solution works at least for me (I had the same very problem) :) Cheers.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  The `/usr/local/bin` version is just a symlink: `/usr/local/bin/pdftk -> /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/pdftk` and it appears to find an older version of the libc++ library running from the (default) path.  Running the `/opt/pdflabs...` version directly avoids the linker error, or you can do `sudo cp /opt/pdflabs/pdftk/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib /usr/local/lib/` to replace the older library.

Answer (score 3):

I found `pdftk_uninstall.sh` script on `/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/` directory.

I copy-past script with `-f` flag for `rm` command

```
rm -f /usr/share/man/man1/pdftk.1;rm -f "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/man/pdftk"*;rm -f /usr/local/bin/pdftk;rm -f "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/bin/pdftk"*;rm -f "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/license_gpl_pdftk/reference/"*;rmdir "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/license_gpl_pdftk/reference";rm -f "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/license_gpl_pdftk/third_party/"*;rmdir "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/license_gpl_pdftk/third_party";rm -f "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/license_gpl_pdftk/"*;rmdir "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/license_gpl_pdftk";rm -f "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/changelog.html" "/opt/pdflabs/pdftk/changelog.txt"
```

This help for me