# how to uninstall pdftk completely from mac?

Tags: macos, pdftk

I am having trouble with pdftk on my Mac OS X 10.13 and want to remove all traces of it from my system before attempting to make a new install with the newest package 2.02 (using this https://gist.github.com/jvenator/9672772a631c117da151) which I already installed.

Now i want to remove it completely.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I completely remove (all versions of) pdftk server from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289231/how-do-i-completely-remove-all-versions-of-pdftk-server-from-mac-os-x)