# pdftk on MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3 : "Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib"

Tags: macos, pdf, libstdc++

I tried to use `pdftk` command to handle different pdf files.

But unfortunaltely, it doesn't work. There seems that libstdc++.6.dylib is missing into MacOS Big Sur 11.2.3.

Here an example of command tried (extract the 4th page) :

```
$ pdftk example1.pdf cat 4 output example2.pdf
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/pdftk
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /usr/local/bin/pdftk
zsh: abort      pdftk example1.pdf cat 4 output
```

How can I solve this issue ?

If I do a `ls -l` into `/usr_lib/libstdc++*`, I get :

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/libstdc++.*
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 17 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libstdc++.dylib -> libstdc++.6.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x 1 root 21 Jan  1  2020 /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib -> libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib
```

and file `libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib` is missing : is it normal ?

Both `macports` and `brew` fail to install `pdftk`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I completely remove (all versions of) pdftk server from Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34289231/how-do-i-completely-remove-all-versions-of-pdftk-server-from-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`__ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev` is the mangled name for

`std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()`

That's definitely a libstdc++ thing; libc++ doesn't have a namespace `__cxx11`.

Apple has not shipped libstdc++ on Mac OS for a long time (several releases). They use libc++ instead.

I wonder why the Mac version of pdftk wants libstdc++

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. How could I circumvent this missing library, I can't copy the file into /usr/lib since `csr SIP` protection enabled ?