# Fill Pdf Form in Ruby using pdf-form gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I want to programmatically fill a pdf using [pdf-form](https://github.com/jkraemer/pdf-forms) gem

I was able to read the fields using the following code:

```
require 'pdf_forms'
pdftk = PdfForms.new('/usr/local/bin/pdftk')
fields = pdftk.get_fields('*/Desktop/sample_pdf.pdf')
for f in fields
  print f.to_s
end
```

But when I tried to fill the Pdf with the provide synthax, I created only an empty, not openable pdf.

```
pdftk.fill_form '/path/to/form.pdf', 'target.pdf', ['Value Name'] => 'Value to be inserted'
```

Does anybody know a working solution?

Thanks in advance!!!

---

Additional Information:

- the fields of the pdf are the following: Name, Address, Dropdown1, Dropdown2, Dropdown3, Check Box4, Check Box1, Check Box3, Check Box2, Text5, Button7, Text6, Group6, %
- I tried it with filling just one field:

pdftk.fill_form 'sample_pdf.pdf', 'sample_pdf_filled.pdf', {["Name"]=>"Value to be inserted"}

The result: I have an pdf "sample_pdf_filled.pdf", which I cannot open, because it's empty. I thought my problem is the form-filling, but it seems, that the pdf is not created correctly.

Note: I am working on a mac (unix)

Has anybody a solution?

Comment: Maybe try `:'value name'` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method `#fill_form` is defined like this:

```
 def fill_form(template, destination, data = {}, fill_options = {})
```

You example would produce something like this:

```
irb(main):001:0> { ['Value Name'] => 'Value to be inserted' }                                                                                   
=> {["Value Name"]=>"Value to be inserted"}
```

The data is supposed to be a Hash. If you want to specify a key with a space you can use it like this: `:'Value Name'`.

```
irb(main):002:0> { :'Value Name' => 'Value to be inserted' }                                                                                    
=> {:"Value Name"=>"Value to be inserted"}
```

Comment: Hey DiodonHystrix, thanks for your answer. I thing the problem is more in the correct pdf creation, could you guess why?

Comment: Did you try `pdftk.fill_form 'sample_pdf.pdf', 'sample_pdf_filled.pdf', {["Name"]=>"Value to be inserted"}` without `[]`?

Comment: Yes, tried it, but had the same result. It seems like the script is not finishing

Comment: Sorry, Did you try `:Name` ? Could you try looking into this [topic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505951/pdftk-server-on-os-x-10-11)

Comment: Ok. One more thing, could you show the output of `pdftk.get_field_names 'sample_pdf.pdf'`?

Comment: of course, it's: ["Name", "Address", "Dropdown1", "Dropdown2", "Dropdown3", "Check Box4", "Check Box1", "Check Box3", "Check Box2", "Text5", "Button7", "Text6", "Group6"]%

Comment: Would you mind uploading the pdf form you are using?

Comment: No problem, its [link](https://1drv.ms/b/s!ApPuG86T8sTFgXtwX-SydJmLrTXY)

Comment: I downloaded your file. Did this: `pdftk.fill_form 'sample_pdf.pdf', 'target.pdf', { Name: 'baaa1', Address: 'dfsdf' }` and it worked :( Not sure what else we can check...

Comment: on which system did  you run it? (osx, linux, windows)

Comment: I tried it with your code, but it seems like the script got stuck somewhere.. so seems to be another issue - nevertheless thanks a lot for helping me, at least I know that the script is correct

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Do you have to interrupt your console or does it finish the process?

Comment: Yes, I had to interrupt. A following print-statement was not executed.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution - for all MAC OS X 10.11 El Capitan User:

[PDFtk Server on OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505951/pdftk-server-on-os-x-10-11/33248310#33248310)