# PDFtk Server on macOS High Sierra 10.13

Tags: macos, pdf, pdftk, macos-high-sierra

I'm currently running PDFtk Server successfully on macOS Sierra without issues with @Sid Steward's update pkg file found here: [PDFtk Server on OS X 10.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505951/pdftk-server-on-os-x-10-11).

Yet I have reservations moving to High Sierra because the new Apple File System (APFS) is default on this release, therefore I don't know this will break PDFtk server.

Has anyone got PDFtk Server running correctly on macOS High Sierra 10.13?  If not what are the issues?

Answer (score 12):

I have updated to 10.13. It works :-)

You must use the update file you linked to in that thread. Here is a direct link for people.

https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.02-mac_osx-10.11-setup.pkg

On pdflab's website, they still link to the old 10.6 version for some reason.